# Recover NTFS partition from failing hard drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

I have a 1TB laptop hard drive (not an SSD) that has failed from a Windows 10 computer. I have created a disk image from the partition using ddrescue, which has recovered 99.99% of the disk. However, it appears the data I want is in the 0.01% that I cannot.

When I mount the image over loopback, I can see all data, except in C:\users, the owner's home directory seems to be corrupted. The directory listing looks like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8.0K Sep 17 18:43 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root   84 Sep 15  2018 All Users -> /media/ProgramData
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? Amy
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8.0K May  3 09:57 Default
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Apr 12  2019 Default.migrated
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root   92 Sep 15  2018 Default User -> /media/Users/Default
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  174 Sep 15  2018 desktop.ini
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K May  3 10:08 Public
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12K May  6 07:48 UpdatusUser
```

I've duplicated the drive to a scratch disk and attempted to view the data in windows. After a long checkdisk, the Amy directory disappears entirely.

It seems that the directory entry for Amy is corrupt.  Since it's a standard windows directory, it will contain the usual subdirectories: "Desktop", "Documents", "Pictures", etc.

Is there a tool or process to recover those subdirectories or to repair the directory so I can get the files within?  Thanks in advance.

PS: Last run of ddrescue below:

```
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Initial status (read from mapfile)
rescued: 975776 MB, tried: 2955 kB, bad-sector: 2955 kB, bad areas: 396

Current status
     ipos:    9592 MB, non-trimmed:    5103 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:    9592 MB, non-scraped:    2283 kB,  average rate:    3372 B/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:    3542 kB,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:  975824 MB,   bad areas:      479,        run time:  3h 57m 26s
pct rescued:   99.99%, read errors:     1363,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:     27m 35s
Scraping failed blocks... (forwards)^C        
  Interrupted by user
```

Comment: Can you attempt a chkdsk on the image from Windows? You can also run ntfsfix on the SSD, but it could potentially be dangerous, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I duplicated my image file over to a scratch drive and ran chkdsk under Windows to fix it. The "Amy" folder disappeared from `C:\Users`, but I've found it (or most of it anyways) in `C:\found.000`!

Windows hides the `found.000` folder by default, so at first I thought that it wasn't working. You have to go into the view options and uncheck the "Hide protected operating system files" box to be able to see it.

I saw it when I had the disk mounted under Linux, so I knew to look for it after the reboot.

Thank you Varun, for your helpful comment!